# Handler and thread ui update

Tags: android, callback

I have created a handler inside an activity(Lets say "**FirstActivity**") and pass this **handler to a thread**. Now I wants to update ui inside the `handleMessage()` by calling the `handler.obtainMessage(100).sendToTarget()` from thread. The thread take time of 20 to 30 seconds to pass the message to the UI.

Now my questions are:
   I switch to another activity(Lets say "SecondActivity") before the `callback(handleMessage())` of "FirstActivity" calls then:

     
1. Is the "FirstActivity" has been available for Garbage Collection?
     
2. If we finish the "FirstActivity" and move to "SecondActivity" then views on "FirstActivity" are available or become null? If not become null then why because "FirstActivity" got finished at this point of time and if we wants to update views then it should throw NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your code for UI update goes here.
            }
    });
```

Its simple.above code will let you update your ui from handler.

Answer (score 0):

If we finish the first activity it wont be available anymore..
if you want to update the first activity again you should pass the intent to first activity. 
then you should update.. that time you wont get null pointer exception. 
You should gothrough the Activity Lifecycle for this .